# How to get an object (image) from S3 using s3fs in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was able to put objects into my S3 bucket using the [s3fs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs), but I can't find a way to retrieve those objects. Specifically, I want to retrieve an object by it's key, and I want to get a URL of that object which I would send back to the client to be rendered in an img tag. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When your bucket is mounted via S3FS, you could use shell command to retrieve files(objects) in the mountpoint, e.g. `/mnt/bucket-name`, and use system call to operate files include retrieving.